# Docker "Failed to solve: Canceled: context canceled" when loading build context

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When running `docker-compose up --build` I'm constantly getting this error.

```
 => [web internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.58kB                                                                             0.0s
 => [web internal] load .dockerignore                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 279B                                                                                  0.0s
 => [web internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.8                                                  0.8s
 => CANCELED [web  1/14] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.8@sha256:7a82536f5a2895b70416ccaffc49e6469d11ed8d9bf6bcf  0.3s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/python:3.8@sha256:7a82536f5a2895b70416ccaffc49e6469d11ed8d9bf6bcfc52328faeae7c77  0.2s
 => => sha256:795c73a8d985b6d1b7e5730dd2eece7f316ee2607544b0f91841d4c4142d9448 7.56kB / 7.56kB                     0.0s
 => => sha256:7a82536f5a2895b70416ccaffc49e6469d11ed8d9bf6bcfc52328faeae7c7710 1.86kB / 1.86kB                     0.0s
 => => sha256:129534c722d189b3baf69f6e3289b799caf45f75da37035c854100852edcbd7d 2.01kB / 2.01kB                     0.0s
 => CANCELED [web internal] load build context                                                                     0.1s
 => => transferring context: 26.00kB                                                                               0.0s
failed to solve: Canceled: context canceled
```

This has been happening since yesterday, before my images would build and my application would run just fine.

1. Tried identifying any processes/apps that interfere with the docker build process
2. Reinstalled Docker Desktop completely
3. Tried changing Python versions inside my Dockerfile

I'm quite lost as to what is going wrong, I've used `python3.8` and `python3.9` without issues before. Below is my dockerfile and docker-compose.

```
# Use an official Python runtime as the base image
FROM python:3.8

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV NODE_ENV production

# Create and set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        default-mysql-client \
        software-properties-common \
        curl \
        gnupg \
    && curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/nodesource.gpg \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_20.x bullseye main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Verify that Node.js and npm are installed
RUN node --version
RUN npm --version

# Install Python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt

# Install Tailwind CSS and its peer dependencies
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

# Copy the current directory contents into the container
COPY . .

# Build the Tailwind CSS
RUN npm run build:css

RUN npm run watch:css

COPY entrypoint.sh ./entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]

# The main command to run when the container starts
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", ":8000", "bmlabs.wsgi:application"]
```

Docker-compose

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 
      MYSQL_DATABASE:
      MYSQL_USER: 
      MYSQL_PASSWORD:
    networks:
      - backend

  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - static_volume:/app/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/app/mediafiles
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - backend
    expose:
      - "8000"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./nginx/bmlabs.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/bmlabs.conf:ro
      - static_volume:/app/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/app/mediafiles
    depends_on:
      - web
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:

volumes:
  db_data:
  cache_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

I am on Windows 10.

Comment: What is `cache_data:`your text``?

Comment: I made a formatting mistake in my post, in my docker-compose it's just `cache_data:`

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Can't find any help on this error

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Altough downgrading docker worked, the actual problem was that I didn't exclude node_modules in Dockerignore. I had been running the containers fine for quite a long time.

After purging all containers and images and adding the `node_modules/` line to my `.dockerignore` it fixed it.

I'm guessing the error had to do with the amount of files inside certain directories.

Comment: Thanks. Adding a .dockerignore file in the same dir as the Dockerfile worked for me. It contained: "# Exclude all files with the .git extension
*.git

# Exclude all files in the node_modules directory
**/node_modules/"

Comment: In python project I found similar solution: adding `venv/` directory to `.dockerignore` helped.

Comment: @MattiLehtinen proposal also worked for me. It seems by design, docker does checks automatically to ensure unnecessary files are not added to the image so the containers remain as lean as possible. All unnecessary files to the image build like .venv/ to be placed in .dockerignore

Comment: I was getting the same error this idea worked for me too, in my case I added .local to my .dockerignore file and ran 'docker builder prune --all' before building my container.

Comment: Your error shows `docker.io/library/python:`, not `docker.io/library/node:`?

Answer (score 6):

Two solutions I found:

1. Moving the docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile to another directory fixed this.
2. Re-cloning project into a different sub directory (or any other dir as long as its different):

- old: /project
- new: /temp/project

I've been having the same exact problem. I was just finishing a long day of developing and I probably ran the same docker-compose.yml file 1000 times, and then all of a sudden it stopped working with a similar error.

> failed to solve: Canceled: context canceled

I tried:

-restarting docker
-restarting my computer
-reinstalling docker
-killed all containers
-deleted all containers, images, volumes

Comment: Re-cloning into a new folder worked for me as well, thank you

Answer (score 4):

If someone is having this issue with any of the IDEs of the Jetbrains family,  Phpstorm, PyCharm etc.

You need to add .idea to the .dockerignore

Comment: This is what helped me

Answer (score 1):

If your using Windows 11, and using WSL engine in your docker desktop app, Apparently you need to **run the docker command from wsl**

```
wsl
docker compose up --build
```

It's not on the docs at lease non that I cloud find.

Found the answer [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13812)

###### Update

Also another strange issue is that sometimes I need to close my IDE (WebStorm) and run the command from an external command line (Might be related to permissions or file locking etc.??)

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar problem.
The options proposed by [Maxwell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15878490/maxwell) worked, but only once. In order to rebuild the container again, I had to either move the Docker files or clone the project.

In the end, it helped to downgrade to Docker Desktop version 4.22.0

NB!: docker installed on Windows 11.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this issue happened to me after Docker Desktop updated to version 4.26. However, I've read in other online forums that some earlier versions also have this problem.

The solution I found was to downgrade to **version 4.19**.

Here's a link I found with older versions of Docker Desktop for Windows. I recommend downloading version 4.19 or earlier. Because from version 4.20 onwards, it's the same installer. Therefore, it will always download the most recent version currently available (version 4.26 on 8/12/2023), which has this bug.

https://wingetgui.com/apps/Docker-DockerDesktop